# Data come from API, but does not display. Angular 9 ABP framework

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, abp

I want to populate data in my select control which is placed in the header child component, but data comes from the API, but it does not display.

[image].

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this._assingedSiteService.getAssignedSitesForLogInUser().subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.sites = res;
        console.log(this.sites);
      },

      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let site of sites">
      {{site.siteName | json}}
    </option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the received data before rendering the page. You can do two things:

1. Use a boolean and `ngIf` directive so:

   ```
    loadingData = true;
    ngOnInit() {
        this._assingedSiteService.getAssignedSitesForLogInUser().subscribe((res) => {
            this.sites = res;
            console.log(this.sites);
            this.loadingData = false;
          }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    }
   ```

   Template

   ```
      <select class="form-control" *ngIf="!loadingData">
        <option *ngFor="let site of sites">
          {{site.siteName | json}}
        </option>
      </select>
   ```
2. Which I prefer, if you have no logic inside your subscription, use `async` pipe inside your template:

   ```
    sites$: Observable<Site>;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.sites$ = this._assingedSiteService.getAssignedSitesForLogInUser();
    }
   ```

   Template:

   ```
      <select class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let site of sites$ | async">
          {{site.siteName | json}}
        </option>
      </select>
   ```